# Move column up on smaller devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout:

```
[blurb] (8) [form] (4)
```

This is very simple, I want the [blurb] to be col-md-8 and the [form] to be col-md-4, so that they become full width on smaller devices.

Right now this happens on smaller devices:

```
[blurb] (12)
[form] (12)
```

I want the [form] to be above the [blurb] on smaller devices so it is like this:

```
[form] (12)
[blurb] (12)
```

I can't figure out the push/pull classes to make this work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think mobile first, so if you want `form` before `blurb` on a small device, your HTML should be that way. And then on larger use push and pull to change the order.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">form</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8">blurb</div>
</div>
```